# SWIFT: Checking data IF EXIST before saving into sqlite

Tags: swift, core-data

I can save data into sqlite database by SWIFT in this way.

```
    for aItem in jsonItems {

    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let moContext:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let ModelAnimal = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("TBL_animal", inManagedObjectContext: moContext) as! ModelAnimal

     ModelAnimal.wId = aItem["wId"] as? NSNumber
     ModelAnimal.wName = aItem["wName"] as? String

                            do {
                                try moContext.save()

                            } catch {
                                print("Data not Saved in Database")
                            }

                        }
```

But what is the easiest way to check IF EXIST before saving data into sqlite?

Comment: I am assuming you are using CoreData, not sqlite or SQL!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Core Data you check whether an entry already exists by fetching it, with a predicate that uses whatever field(s) would identify a unique entry. Assuming that your `wId` is unique, you'd do something like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"TBL_animal"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"wId = %@", ModelAnimal.wId"];
fetch.predicate = predicate;

NSError *error = nil;
NSUInteger count = [moContext countForFetchReuqest:fetch error:&error];
```

That'll tell you how many existing objects match your predicate.